# Saving incorrect date in MySQL Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am writing below code to convert the data to Date.

```
$date = strtotime($request->input('DueDate'));
$Job->DueDate = date('Y-m-d', $date);
$Job->save();
```

But this saves the data as `0000-00-00`

Comment: What is $request->input('DueDate') returning?

Comment: It returns `1/13/2000`.

Comment: @PankajGarg Do you think it's what the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this maybe: (**createFromFormat's first argument should be the format which is being received by the user**)

```
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', strtotime($request->input('DueDate')));
$Job->DueDate = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
$Job->save();
```

Cheers,,

Answer (score 0):

Let say your `DueDate` is correctly return the data. Try this:

```
$date = Carbon::parse($request->input('DueDate'))->format('Y-m-d');
$Job->DueDate = $date;
$Job->save();
```

Use carbon instance. For more docs [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com)

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP manual for `strtotime()`

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (-, the date string is parsed as y-m-d.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

So the simplest mod for your situation would be to just convert the slashes to hyphens like this

```
$fixDate = str_replace('/', '-', $request->input('DueDate'));
$date = strtotime($fixDate);
$Job->DueDate = date('Y-m-d', $date);
$Job->save();
```